# IIS 7.5 shows aspx but no content

Tags: iis, iis-7.5

I recently switched from Vista to Windows 7 (with IIS 7.5). But i can't seem to get it fully working.
My problem: I run Visual Studio 2008 (sp1) (run as administrator) and i see my WebSite (webforms).

I publish my website, and all seems well, except my layout is wasted.. why? i get a 404 on my CSS and javascript file.

I read an article that you need content server (service?) installed. After some translation i figured that should be "Statische inhoud" (dutch.. translated static content).

I triple checked that the .js and .css files are in te folder i'm pointing to (tried root folder of the website), but all in veighn...

Here is my IIS-component list that is installed (in dutch). 
Anyone able to figure out why i get 404's? or even beter, how do i fix it?

http://img69.imageshack.us/img69/4026/iis.png

Comment: Is your firewall allowing your webserver through?  I don't think it's got anything to do with installed components on your PC.  More like a config issue.

Comment: Yes i was asuming that it didn't have to do with installed components, but just to be sure i posted it. I just disabled the firewall, and still a 404 on the CSS though.

Comment: by the way, perhaps for other people a fix, the article i found on iis issues with 404 and static content:
http://weblogs.asp.net/meligy/archive/2009/10/12/funny-problem-windows-7-iis-7-5-images-css-not-showing.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, i finally figured it out :)

Hope some else will be helped by this answer:
It was related to the Static File Module.

Microsoft has a solution which did not work for me.
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/942052/

It was already configured this way.
But i deleted it, added it again, i could access my CSS... but ASPX didn't work anymore. The Fix for that issue: Make the list Sorted, and move your static filehandler to the bottom (or a least after aspx, but probably the best is at the bottem).

Thanxs everyone for the pointers though!

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem and spent 6 hours doing research and trying out many suggested solutions.
We resolved this by granting the default IIS user access to the application folder.